# My modelformset_factory is not saving the images ( I used the Class based views), but saving it, when using the Admin side

Tags: python, django, django-forms, django-templates, django-views

I have a challenge of not saving the image when creating a new product. The form is rendered well and the image is uploaded but never saved until I use the Admin to upload and save it, thats when it becomes visible on my created product.

I think I'm missing something in my class `ProductCreateView()` in the views.py, especially in the `def post()` . 
Help me to figure it out.

**models.py**

```
def product_download(instance, filename):
  return '%s/%s' %(instance.product.slug, filename)

class ProductImages(models.Model):
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=120)
    media = models.ImageField(upload_to=product_download, 
        width_field='max_width', 
        height_field='max_height',
        null=True, blank=True)
    max_width = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True, blank=True)
    max_height = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True, blank=True)
    featured_image = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, auto_now=False)
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=False, auto_now=True)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return unicode(self.media)
```

**views.py**

the form is saving its information well, but formset is not saving the images

```
from .forms import ProductModelForm, ProductImagesForm, ImagesFormset

class ProductCreateView(CreateView):

    def form_invalid(self, form, formset):
        return self.render_to_response(self.get_context_data(form=form, formset=formset))

    def form_valid(self, form, formset):
        return HttpResponseRedirect(self.get_success_url())

    def get(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.object = None
        form_class = self.get_form_class()
        form = self.get_form(form_class)
        formset = ImagesFormset(queryset=ProductImages.objects.none())
        return self.render_to_response(self.get_context_data(form=form, formset=formset))

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        self.object = None
        form_class = self.get_form_class()
        form = self.get_form(form_class)
        formset = ImagesFormset(self.request.POST, self.request.FILES)
        form_valid = form.is_valid()
        formset_valid = formset.is_valid()
        if form_valid and formset_valid:
            user = self.request.user
            form.instance.user = user
            self.object = form.save()
            media = formset.save(commit=False)
            for img in media:
                if hasattr(self.model, 'product'):
                    img.save()
                    formset = self.object
            formset.save()  
            return self.form_valid(form, formset)
        else:
            return self.form_invalid(form, formset)
```

**forms.py**

```
class ProductImagesForm(forms.ModelForm):
    media = forms.ImageField(label='Image')
    featured_image = forms.BooleanField(initial=True) 

    def __init__ (self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(ProductImages, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['featured_image'] = forms.BooleanField( widget = forms.RadioSelect(attrs={'checked': 'true'}, choices=((self.prefix, 'featured'),)))


    def add_prefix(self, field):
        if field == 'featured_image': return field
        else: return self.prefix and ('%s-%s' % (self.prefix, field)) or field

    class Meta:
        model = ProductImages
        fields = ['media', 'featured_image', ]
    ImagesFormset = modelformset_factory(ProductImages, fields=('media', 'featured_image'), extra=1, max_num=4)
```

**template**

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="" method="POST"> {% csrf_token %} 

{{ form.as_p }}

{{ formset.management_form }}
<div class="link-formset">

{{  formset .as_p }}

</div>
</form>
```

Comment: I don't understand what you're doing inside that `if valid` block. As far as I can see, you are never setting `self.model`, so you will never reach `img.save()`. And what is the point of `formset = self.object`?

Comment: What is the best approach to fill in the missing pieces

Answer (score 1):

If this answer is wrong, please pardon me for mistake.

I think the error is here,

```
for img in media:
    img.product = self.object
    img.save()
    #why assigning formset to self.object? , try removing this.
    #self.object is form.save(), ie, already saved.
    #formset = self.object
```

Comment: Thanks, but this is producing an Exception. RelatedObjectDoesNotExist at /seller/products/add/                                                                        ProductImages has no product.

Comment: whats the exception?

Comment: RelatedObjectDoesNotExist at /seller/products/add/ ProductImages has no product.

Comment: Is self.object the so called product object?

Comment: yeah, that it the related Object

Comment: its giving this Exception -----> 'list' object has no attribute 'product'

Comment: AttributeError at /seller/products/add/      'list' object has no attribute 'product'

Comment: add 'product' to your form and then try this, it should work.

Comment: Now this saves the product, but the image is not saved and still I have to run to the Admin side and upload the image, Just like before

Comment: try removing the if hasattr(), and then save the img

Comment: this means I should have the form and the formset on different HTML pages and will upload the images after saving the form

Comment: you should save the form first, then add the image and then associate image with the product object

Comment: Thanks for the effort, but when I did the same on the Admin by saving a new product, altogether with its image, without separating the 2 stages, it worked. Meaning there is a way it can workout. I will keep going and find it out. Appreciate your effort @Fazil Zaid

Comment: Okay, but keep thinking, it can be a great learning opportunity for both of us.

Comment: Hey @Fazil Zaid, Are there bro

Answer (score 1):

This way simpler, just associate it with the product and the problem will be solved

```
if form_valid and formset_valid:
            seller = self.get_account()
            form.instance.seller = seller
            self.object = form.save()
            media = formset.save(commit=False)
            for img in media:
                img.product = self.object
                img.save()
            formset.save()
```

Answer (score 0):

I finally got the missing pieces after a long time of reading, by associating the image with the product and its now saving and producing the image well

```
if form_valid and formset_valid:
            seller = self.get_account()
            form.instance.seller = seller
            self.object = form.save()
            media = formset.save(commit=False)
            for img in media:
                img.product = self.object
                img.save()
            formset.save()
```